# How to make custom fields show up in Products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wondering if you can help me. I'm developing a site & I started off with a development website (Lets call it Site A). I have now moved onto the final build of the website (Site B) & am moving the products over to the new website.

I made a custom field for all products in Site A called 'product_group'. I've exported a .csv file of all the products from site A which contains the product_group column and the corresponding letter (A,B,C,D).

I am now trying to import the products into the new store, and even though the product group custom field is on the new website. I have to manually add the custom field to all products (There's 300 products....)

Is there any way to do this automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access of both sites, you can copy all the folders and database from one site to another.

You do not need to transfer it manually. Copy all folders and files of your `Site A` to `Site B`, export database of `Site A` and import it in `Site B` and run following sql query in the database of Site B

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://sitea.com', 'http://siteb.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://sitea.com','http://siteb.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://sitea.com', 'http://siteb.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=REPLACE(meta_value,'http://sitea.com', 'http://siteb.com');
```

Remember to change table prefix and site url in above codes

Comment: The old website was very slow, as it was development site, I do not want to reproduce the slowness

Comment: You can find the cause of slowness and avoid it.

Comment: I do not want to do this. Could you advise how to do what i asked in the question please

Comment: You can only export wp_posts and wp_postmeta table from database of old site and import into new site to transfer custom fields.

Comment: I have the custom field in the new website, i just have to go through all products and select it manually for each...

Comment: If you do not want to do it through database, there is no way of doing it manually. If you have used ACF plugin, it would provide export and import functionality.